# Exception Retrieving the COM class factory in ASP.net web app

Tags: asp.net, com, iis-7, microsoft-bits

I am getting this exception within my ASP.net web application

> EXCEPTION: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID
>   {4991D34B-80A1-4291-83B6-3328366B9097}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80070005 Access is denied.

I did some research and found out this is an issue between COM and BITS, not quite sure exactly of the details.

How do I resolve this issue? The application is hosted on IIS7, are there settings required on the IIS side perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue a while back, and here is the solution:

There is a permission issue between COM and BITS if DCOM is not configured with the right permissions for the IIS user, here are the instructions for configuring COM:

1)  Open component services
2)  Navigate to Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config
3)  Right-click Background Intelligent Transfer Service and select Properties
4)  Select the Security tab
5)  Select Customize under Launch and Activation Permissions and click Edit
6)  Add user web services are running under
7)  Check Allow for Local Launch and Local Activation
8)  Reset IIS